# angular 2 singleton service not working for me

Tags: angular

The summary of what I have done is 
1) created a simple service that stores a string value. 
2) provided for in the appModule. 
3) created 2 components: first and second. I do not provide for the service in the components - but inject the service through the constructors. 
4) added 2 routes for navigating between first and second. first component saves a string into the service, second component should retrieve back the stored string from the service - this is NOT working. 
I have researched for 2 days for a solution, gone over tutorials - seems like it should work! None of solved answers here on stackoverflow seem to provide a clear solution for me. Everything else is working.  Imports are ok - no compilation or run-time errors in browser.

Please help.

Here are the code snippets without the obvious imports:

```
// app.module.ts
...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'first', component: FirstComponent},
  {path: 'second', component: SecondComponent},
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent,
    SecondComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// first component
...

import {DataService} from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  localToken: string;

  constructor(private svc: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.svc.save("000000");
  }

}


// second component
...
import {DataService} from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  localToken: string;

  constructor(private svc: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK !!!
    this.localToken = this.svc.retrieve();

  }

}
```

Q: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are u navigating from one coponent to another? Are you changing the URL byurself which mean u are refeshing the browser everytime then it will not work. because when you refresh you will earse alll the temp memory.

Comment: could you please provide plnkr link?

Comment: Your service must be Injectable. Can you please also post the code from the Dataservice

Comment: the code is here:  https://github.com/gkabule/test01

Comment: Seems to work just fine https://plnkr.co/edit/AOvRh2jWdRNb8eGTlHcH?p=previewhttps://plnkr.co/edit/AOvRh2jWdRNb8eGTlHcH?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

With the help from Simona, I finally got the singleton service working fine!

- create the service
- import it into the appModule
- add it to the providers array

in the component(s)

- import the service {} from '{path}';
- add/inject it into the constructor as a private parm of the type of
  service imported
- use in the class member methods as this.parm...

works!, thank you Simona

Comment: i am glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) your service must be marked as **Injectable**

> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Injectable() export class HeroService { }

Comment: I am navigating from a nav i provided as follows:

Comment: I am navigating using a <router-outlet> and <a .../> links - very sorry, forgot to include that.  I thought I added the code for the service.  It has one string property, a save(string) and a retrieve: string.  The service has the @Injectable decorator.  I used ng generate service which automatically adds the decorator

Comment: What does this method return: this.svc.retrieve();
You can debug and see if in the save method the value is set.

Comment: the routing is working perfect.  i feel frustrated that i forgot to add the service code - i will paste it here - i know it will not come out properly formated - here goes >>   @Injectable()
export class DataService {
  token: string;

  constructor() { }

  save(_token: string) {
    this.token = _token;
    console.log(this.token);
  }

  retrieve(): string {
    return this.token;
  }
}

Comment: I created the Project localy and tested the code. And its working. You must first call the First Component to set the token, and than call it from the Second Component to get it. Did you check the console for errors ?

Comment: There are no compilation or runtime errors.  No errors show up in the console.  The navigation (via the router) works fine.  The first component has a call inside the ngOnInit to this.svc.save('000000'); The second component has this.svc.retrieve() - this retrives nothing !  I created this as a test for this purpose only - so it is a very trial app which is not working.  I know I am missing something - and that is why I need help (badly!) so I can go passed this stage.  I have put this test application on https://github.com/gkabule/test01  Simona - thanks for staying with me on this

Comment: Simona, would you mind sharing the test project you did?

Comment: Simona.  Your test code works!  I want to say a very big thank for all your assistance - and sticking with me. I will use your code - if you permit, even though, I would like to know if you noticed what exactly I was doing wrong